Cannot set gpt-4 as model for OpenAI in Langchain NodeJS
I cannot set custom api model for OpenAI in langchain init model.
 const llm = new OpenAI({
      model: 'gpt-4',
      apiKey: this.openAiEnv.apiKey,
    })

    console.log(llm.model)

Console  log will return gpt-3.5 for which ever input I put in model
